# Is the approximation of the Medial Frontal Gyrus in the region of the Dorsolateral Prefrontal Cortex?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neuroanatomy

I'm wondering if the MFG is located in the region considered the DLPFC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; the medial frontal gyrus is medial; it faces the sagittal midline of the brain. Medial is the opposite of lateral; the dorsolateral prefrontal cortex is lateral, facing towards the outside of the brain.

Perhaps you are thinking of the *middle* frontal gyrus?